# Determine objects to delete from a database

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following method which determines which cars I need to delete from the DB.

```
private List<CarDTO> BuildCarsToDelete(IList<CarDTO> newCars, IList<CarDTO> existingCars)
{
    var missingCars = new List<CarDTO>();

    var cars = newCars.Select(c => c.CarId);
    var newCarIds = new HashSet<int>(cars);

    foreach (var car in existingCars)
    {
        //If there are no new cars then it had some and they have been removed
        if (newCars.Count() == 0)
        {
            missingCars.Add(car);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!newCarIds.Contains(car.CarId))
            {
                missingCars.Add(car);
            }
        }
    }

    return missingCars;
}
```

This works as expecting - but if I want to achieve the same functionality for Customers or Apartments of other DTOs I will be copying a pasting the code but only changing the variable names and the Type of DTO around - is there a nicer way possible using generics which would keep the algorithm and logic as it is but allow me to use on any DTO?

Comment: Not really code review.  Have your objects implement GetHashCode and Equals.  Or have them implement a base class with ID.

Comment: @Paparazzi - ok makes sense - cheers

Answer (score 7):

There is an easier way to find the cars to delete. You just need to use the `Except` extension.

```
var carsToDelete = existingCars.Except(newCars);
```

In order for this to work you have two choices:

- you can either implement the `IEquatable` for each DTO or
- you can implement a common interface for the `Id` and a custom `IEqualityComparer<IYourInterface>` and use it with the `Except` extension.

Answer (score 2):

No need to implement `IEquatable` on every DTO, nor is a common interface required. Use generics and a lambda to access a property of a given `T`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetItemsToDelete<T, U>(IEnumerable<T> newT, IEnumerable<T> existingT, Func<T, U> selector) {
    return existingT
        .Select(item => new {
            Id = selector(item),
            Item = item
        })
        .Where(a => !newT.Select(selector).Any(b => EqualityComparer<U>.Default.Equals(a.Id, b)))
        .Select(a => a.Item);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var newT = new [] {
    new Person { Id = 0 },
    new Person { Id = 1 }
};
var existingT = new [] {
    new Person { Id = 0 },
    new Person { Id = 1 },
    new Person { Id = 2 }
};

foreach (var item in GetItemsToDelete(newT, existingT, person => person.Id)) {
    // do something with item
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: right, there is a third option ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if fix is code review but use a base class
DTO is what you would pass to your method

```
public abstract class DTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
public class carDTO : DTO
{
    public carDTO (int id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }
}
```

Or have your object implement [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.iequalitycomparer.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) and you can just use Except.  You could have the base class implement the IEqualityComparer so you don't have to repeat.

Or you can pass an IEqualityComparer to [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx)